# How to reduce SQL injection vulnerability attacks?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

How do I make the below code less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks? and also be able to accept " and ' characters in the parameters?

```
app.get('/addStudent',(req,res) => {
  const {fname, lname, othname, bloodType}= req.query;

  let sqlstmt = "INSERT INTO `students` (`fname`, `lname`, `othname`, `bloodtype`) VALUES ('"+fname+"', '"+lname+"', '"+othname+"', '"+bloodType+"')"
    db.query(sqlstmt,(err,result) => {
    if(err){console.log('Error occured while fetching user information',err)}
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use prepared statements which should be supported by your driver package for your chosen DBMS.

An example for MySQL: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries

Comment: Yes, but more to the point, use query parameters. Just doing a prepared statement from a string that has been formed with string-concatenation doesn't magically make it safe.

Comment: how can I modify my above code using query parameters and prepared statements?